# How can I fix my database to get my foreign keys to work in SQLite3 Python?

Tags: python, sqlite3-python

I am attempting to make a database in Python using SQLite3, working around foreign keys doesn't seem to be going to well, I keep getting error messages and i am fully aware my poor formatting is somewhat of a contributor.

## This is all of the code

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("POS SYSTEM.db")
c = conn.cursor()

###################################################################

Suppliers = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Suppliers ( Supplier_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Supplier_Name TEXT NOT NULL)"
c.execute(Suppliers)

Stock_Items = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stock_Items ( Stock_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name_Of_Stock_Item TEXT NOT NULL, Cost_Of_Bulk_Item INTEGER NOT NULL, Supplier_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Suppliers(Supplier_ID))"
c.execute(Stock_Items)

Current_Stock_List = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Current_Stock_List ( Current_Stock_List_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name_Of_CStock_Item TEXT NOT NULL, Spoil_Date DATE NOT NULL, Portions_Per_Bulk_Item INTEGER NOT NULL, Stock_Order_ID INTEGER, Stock_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Stock_ID) REFERENCES Stock_Items(Stock_ID))"
c.execute(Current_Stock_List)

Menu_Items = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Menu_Items ( Menu_Item_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Menu_Name TEXT NOT NULL)"
c.execute(Menu_Items)

Ingredients = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ingredients ( INGMenu_Item_Name TEXT NOT NULL, Ingredient_Name TEXT NOT NULL, Stock_ING_ID INTEGER, Stock_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Stock_ID) REFERENCES Stock_Items(Stock_ID)), Menu_Item_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Menu_Item_ID) REFERENCES Menu_Items(Menu_Item_ID))"
c.execute(Ingredients)
```

This seems to be the problem statement I just can't figure out what's wrong with it, and if i could streamline the process in the future.

```
Ingredients = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ingredients ( INGMenu_Item_Name TEXT NOT NULL,
 Ingredient_Name TEXT NOT NULL, Stock_ING_ID INTEGER,
 Stock_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Stock_ID) REFERENCES Stock_Items(Stock_ID)),
 Menu_Item_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Menu_Item_ID) REFERENCES Menu_Items(Menu_Item_ID))"
c.execute(Ingredients)
```

Running my code presents me with this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): line 23, in <module>       c.execute(Ingredients) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Fiddling with the code I found that declaring foreign keys and then other columns afterwards came with an error message.

```
Stock_Items = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stock_Items ( Stock_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 Name_Of_Stock_Item TEXT NOT NULL,
 Cost_Of_Bulk_Item INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Supplier_ID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Suppliers(Supplier_ID))"
c.execute(Stock_Items)
```

This is that error message which is of course very similar to my main issue i just can't see the problem:

`Traceback (most recent call last): line 17, in <module>       c.execute(Current_Stock_List) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Sorry if this is obvious or a waste of time, I'm still new and learning so thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You have an extra `)` in `REFERENCES  Stock_Items(Stock_ID))`.

Comment: That brings on other errors too actually, although i did miss that completely `Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 17, in <module>      
    c.execute(Current_Stock_List)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Name_Of_CStock_Item": syntax error`

Comment: Which query is that happening with? I don't get any error from `c.execute(Current_Stock_List)` and that's the only one that mentions `Name_Of_CStock_Item`

Comment: Within table Current_Stock_List, it doesn't seem to like "Name_Of_CStock_Item".

Comment: It likes it fine for me. I copied and pasted those two lines and they worked without error.

Comment: Remember that you can put your SQL statements in a text file and use the `sqlite3` command line tool to enter SQL directly.  You don't have to go through Python like this for your setup.

Comment: well then why else wouldn't my code work? all of it is there i just cannot see any errors.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out